# Would Dumbledore know that Lord Voldemort created Horcuxes if Harry had been killed in Godric's Hollow along with his parents?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

If Harry had been *successfully* killed in Godric's Hollow in 1981, would Dumbledore have found out that Voldemort had made Horcruxes?

Comment: Found out how? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Considering that Harry dying would have meant Voldemort _didn't_ die, he'd simply have continued his reign of terror on the Wizarding world and Trelawney would have been ousted as a phony prophecy-maker. Beyond that, this is an extremely broad "What if" questions that I'm not sure anyone would be able to answer.

Comment: Interesting question. Could you clarify it more? Perhaps add some info from the books or potter websites too? :-)

Comment: I think this is answerable, I mean, if you have reference to "Horcruxes" he explains a lot of his sources of information, I think you can make an argument. For me personally (no offence to the OP) I'm not sure I'm in the mood just now, which is why I just left this question, but I'm sure there are plenty of people here who can do it. For: all the research Dumbledore was doing into Voldemort's past, Slughorn's memory, Voldemort's physical transformations. Against: heavy reliance on Harry's evidence (Riddle's diary, Voldemort's speech to his death eaters), needing harry 4 S.horn's memory etc.

Comment: @Au101 I don't believe for a second that Dumbledore *needed* Harry to get Slughorn's memory. I suspect that the alternative was just a road he didn't want to go down unless absolutely required, and he was confident that Harry could obtain it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Hehe well maybe I was just throwing out points that I would use in an answer to show why I think this should be re-opened. I admit for example it's basically impossible to decide whether or not Dumbledore would ever have seen riddle's diary if voldemort had gone on to even great heights after slaughtering the potters. who can say whether the diary would have been used and whether there would have been someone to get it to Dumbledore, or whether he would have got it himself. So there is a lot of speculation, but you can certainly form what i think is a decent answer

Comment: Out of what we know about where Dumbledore's information came from, so I would reopen it